# How can i stop sound

Tags: java, android, audio

When I click button, first sound start, then I click button again first sound stop  and second sound start. How can I do?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.random); 
            final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.stop);
            if(!mStarted) {
                // Start                                    
                mp2.stop();             

                mp.start();     

                Toast.makeText(finish.this, "Started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mStarted = true;
                mInterval = MIN_INTERVAL;
                mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_RANDOM);               
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_RANDOM);


            } else {
                // Stop
                generate.setEnabled(false);
                mp.stop();                          
                mp2.start();    

                mStarted = false;
                Toast.makeText(finish.this, "Stoping...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                               
            }      
        }      
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `mp2.stop()` before `mp.start()` and `mp.stop()` before `mp2.start()`. Don't forget to check if MediaPlayers are initialized and playing via calling

```
if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying())
```

for every MediaPlayer instance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can not add mp2.stop() before mp.start() and mp.stop() before mp2.start(). Because have some error

Comment: @user814154 did you add the checking I've described above?

Comment: i have edit code. First sound don't stop and play together with second sound. How should i do??

Answer (score 0):

```
mp2.stop()
```

is code to stop MediaPlayer in general. But do you need to stop and start or this will do?

Comment: I want start first sound when press button in first time. and after that press button second time first sound stop and second sound start

Answer (score -1):

instead of `mp2.start();` use `mp2.stop();`

Comment: which line can stop mp.stop(); after press button second time